# multiple google maps on the same page are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm just having some trouble with the google maps. When I have multiple google maps in the same page. Different styles, different width, and everything is okay, but the very first one is working the others are not working.

### My html markups are

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="google-map">
        <div id="google-map-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="google-map">
        <div id="google-map-container2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work on js and no errors on the console are logged.

### Js files are

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var latitude = 51.5255069,
    longitude = -0.0836207,
    map_zoom = 14;


var marker_url =  'images/marker.png';

var style= [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"weight":"2.00"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#9c9c9c"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#7b7b7b"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#8cb6b6"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#070707"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}];


var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: map_zoom,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: style,
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#google-map-container'), map_options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    icon: marker_url,
});

<-- style 2 -->

 style2 = [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"weight":"2.00"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#9c9c9c"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#7b7b7b"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#8cb6b6"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#070707"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}];


var map_options2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: map_zoom,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: style2,
}

var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#google-map-container2'), map_options2);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: map2,
    visible: true,
    icon: marker_url,
});

});
```

Comment: new google.maps.Map(document.getElementbyId('google-map-container2'), map_options2);

Comment: Your main problem (in addition to the typo in the id of the second map container) is that your map elements don't have a size (or if they do, you haven't posted the required CSS. [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4z1yuqg4/)

Answer (score 0):

`var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#google-map-container'), map_options2);`

Should be

`var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#google-map-container2'), map_options2);`

Answer (score 0):

change here

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#google-map-container'), map_options);
```

to

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map-container2'), map_options2);
```

I hope this help